# Audience Manager Subscribe Form Exception

Tags: audience-manager

I am trying to add users to Audience Manager from my webapp, and I am receiving the following error message.

> 2013-10-03 00:00:56,758 ERROR Contact - Unable to instantiate contact
>   object com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot find
>   item type mapping in storage configuration: AudienceManagerProfile    at
>   com.tridion.marketingsolution.utilities.DatabaseType.fromStorageConfig(DatabaseType.java:23)
>   ~[oe_utils.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.AudienceManagerProfileDAO.isMSSQL(AudienceManagerProfileDAO.java:39)
>   ~[oe_utils.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ExtendedDetailsDal.getExtendedDetailsDal(ExtendedDetailsDal.java:23)
>   ~[oe_profile.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ExtendedDetails.loadExtendedDetailsTemplate(ExtendedDetails.java:40)
>   ~[oe_profile.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ExtendedDetails.(ExtendedDetails.java:78)
>   ~[oe_profile.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.init(Contact.java:947)
>   ~[oe_profile.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.(Contact.java:737)
>   ~[oe_profile.jar:na]

As far as I can see my config is correct, what am I missing?

```
<StorageBindings>
  <Bundle src="preview_dao_bundle.xml"/>
  <Bundle src="AudienceManagerDAOBundle.xml"/>
</StorageBindings>
...
<Storage Id="profiledb" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory"
         Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
  <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
  <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
    <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVER"/>
    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="tridion_submgmt"/>
    <Property Name="user" Value="USERNAME"/>
    <Property Name="password" Value="PASSWORD"/>
  </DataSource>
</Storage>
...
<item typeMapping="AudienceManagerProfile" storageId="profiledb"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<Item/>` tag is supposed to be use a capital "i".

If you fix that, I'm guessing it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Damn! 20 plus item nodes and only one is lowercase... Thanks!

Comment: Been there, done that :)